# Output query results in HTML table to image

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've done quite a bit of searching with no luck and I'm not sure if this is even possible but if so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a PHP script that queries a database and places the results into an HTML table. I would like to output that table to an image (jpg, png, bmp, whatever...)

I imagine it would have to be in JS or AJAX but any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Put the image URL in the database and then echo the path. If that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise using something like GD. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Also found: [Save HTML table as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591097/save-html-table-as-an-image)

The issue is you have to render the HTML into the Table and then convert that rendered HTML into an Image. Do you have an example of the table? If it's not too complex, you could just draw a table with the results in it.